# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception, but not out of bounds?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a method that edits a record in a CSV file, which should print everything except for the line im editing, then print the edited version onto a new file.

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("PATRON")) {
                pw.println(line);
            }
            if(!line.contains("PATRON")) {
                String[] str = line.split(",", 7);

                if(str[1].equals(ID)) {
                    pw.println(str[0] + "," + ID + "," + str[2] + "," + "false" + "," + "0" + "," + str[5] + "," + "0");
                }else {
                    pw.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

When i try to run this and enter a valid ID, it gives me this exception

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at myproject.Materials.returnmat(Materials.java:296)
at myproject.Library.mmenu(Library.java:121)
at myproject.Library.mainmenu(Library.java:143)
at myproject.Library.main(Library.java:11)
```

However after running some tests,

```
for(int x=0;x<str.length;x++) {
                    System.out.println(x+ ": " +str[x]);
                }
```

It outputs exactly what id expect, 1: 101, 1:102, etc.. 
So this shows me that the ID is definitely at the str[1] index.

Why is it throwing me the exception?

EDIT: If its relevant, here's how im calling it.

```
    case "7": 
            System.out.println("Enter material ID: ");
            String matsid = scan.nextLine();
            mats.returnmat(matsid);
            scan.nextLine();
            break;
```

Comment: Why'd you add the loop to debug? Just add a print statement prior to the line the error gets triggered on. I would add a count variable to see which line number (of the file) the error gets triggered on and I would print out line and str to see why the error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Check your string length before doing if(str[1].equals(ID)) {

Something like :

```
if(str.length<1) { 
    System.out.println("line no good="+line); 
} else ...
```

It's likely you have a bad line in the CSV or maybe this is the last blank line.

Comment: I added this along with some other debugging lines, at the very end its printing String is no good, so it looks like its the last blank line, why doesnt the reader stop since its a null line?

Comment: Because Java interprets the last /r/n or "newline" in the readline function.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
        String[] str = line.split(",", 7);
        if(str[1].equals(ID)) {
```

the splitting line must have had return array of length=1 thus maximum index would be 0 - but you are exceeding it using `str[1]`;